# Weblogic 12c clustering

Tags: weblogic12c

Message icon - Warning All of the servers selected are currently in a state which is incompatible with this operation or are not associated with a running Node Manager or you are not authorized to perform the action requested. No action will be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check status of server is Running and health is ok. If not, then 
check that server belonging to which machine and node manager corresponding to that machine is reachable.